# can't get placeholder attribute to work in IE using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe

iframe in a wordpress, placeholders don't show in IE, BUT they show just fine if you load the iframe directly in IE

http://uslegalsupport.com/contact-us-new/ this is the link with the iframe on the page:

here's the link of JUST the iframe:

https://www.uslegalsupport.com/wp-content/themes/us-legal/ifpage-contact-us.php

this is literally driving me insane...plz help!

Comment: start by fixing your script errors

Comment: what errors are you referring to? thanks for the input!

Comment: the ones thrown in browser console

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the latest rendering engine with `IE=edge` in both the frame and its parent.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Terry, however, this did not work. Any other ideas?